# What is the name of the audio equipment Charlie Puth has on this top shelf of his rack? (the one with the orange logo?)

Tags: audio, audio-interfaces

What is the name of the audio equipment Charlie Puth has on this top shelf of his rack? (the one with the orange logo?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find it in here... 
https://equipboard.com/pros/charlie-puth

"The Dangerous Music Monitor ST is the gold standard for studio reference. Input source selection, speaker switching, cue system, talkback functions, and headphone amplification are all neatly tucked into one rack space and controlled via the comprehensive, customizable remote. As with every Dangerous Music product, painstaking measures are taken to create complete functionality with ZERO audio compromise. Expansion to 5.1 and beyond is simple: just add the Monitor SR and/or the Additional Switching System. The Monitor ST solves the conundrum of today's complex monitoring world, without masking reality."

Comment: yes, looks it's the last drawer in https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/DangerousSys--dangerous-music-complete-mixing-and-mastering-system